# Run program remotely

Tags: c++, .net, windows, active-directory

I need to be able to run n program on different machines that jointed to Active Directory by user and password of AD.
For example, I want to copy an exe file and run it on another PC with valid AD user/pass.
Can I run it from .NET or C++?
How can I do?

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use psexec to run your program on a remote machine:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

You could write a C# or C++ program that runs psexec for you and passes it different arguments for each target machine.

Comment: Search stackoverflow for how to run a program from C# or C++, I'm sure there are plenty of answers already on how to do that.